# Executing SQL Through Tkinter Commands

Tags: python, mysql

```
import mysql.connector
from Tkinter import *
def Db_Connection():
cnx =     mysql.connector.connect    (user='root', password='BlahBlahBlah',
                                      host='127.0.0.1',
                                      database='school')
Db_Connection()

Class Login:
def __init__(self,master):
frame = Frame(master)
frame.pack()
self.Login = Button(frame, text="Login", command=self.login_db)
self.login.pack(side=LEFT)
self.quitButton = Button(frame, text="Quit", command=master.quit)
self.quitButton.pack(side=LEFT)
def login_db():
    cursor.execute(SELECT * FROM teacher;)
root= Tk()

b = Login(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The Error I get is that teacher is not a valid syntax, even though I am executing through the cursor.execute function. How can I make my program execute the database search when the login button is clicked. I replaced the 'cursor.execute' with simple 'print(123)' and it worked, it is executing MySQL code that I am struggling with.

Comment: your indentation is messed up, and it would make your code more readable if you didn't have a blank line between every statement. Also, "teacher is not a valid syntax" isn't a python error message. Can you please post the _actual_ error message?

Comment: Syntax error: there is an error in your program, invalid syntax, (highlights the word 'teacher')